# Cumulative apply within window defined by other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a function, cumulatively, to values that lie within a window defined by 'start' and 'finish' columns. So, 'start' and 'finish' define the intervals where the value is 'active'; for each row, I want to get a sum of all 'active' values at the time.

Here is a 'bruteforce' example that does what I am after - is there a more elegant, faster or more memory efficient way of doing this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,3,100], [2,4,200], [3,6,300], [4,6,400], [5,6,500]],
    columns=['start', 'finish', 'val'])
df['dummy'] = 1
df = df.merge(df, on=['dummy'], how='left')
df = df[(df['start_y'] <= df['start_x']) & (df['finish_y'] > df['start_x'])]
val = df.groupby('start_x')['val_y'].sum()
```

Originally, df is:

```
  start  finish  val
0   1      3     100
1   2      4     200
2   3      6     300
3   4      6     400
4   5      6     500
```

The result I am after is:

```
1   100
2   300
3   500
4   700
5   1200
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `numpy` boardcast , unfortunately it is still O(n*m) solution , but should be faster than the `groupby`. So far base on my test [Pir 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53265509/7964527) performance is the best

```
s1=df['start'].values
s2=df['finish'].values
np.sum(((s1<=s1[:,None])&(s2>=s2[:,None]))*df.val.values,1)
Out[44]: array([ 100,  200,  300,  700, 1200], dtype=int64)
```

---

Some timing

```
#df=pd.concat([df]*1000)
%timeit merged(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 5.02 s per loop
%timeit npb(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 283 ms per loop
% timeit PIR(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.8 ms per loop
```

---

```
def merged(df):
    df['dummy'] = 1
    df = df.merge(df, on=['dummy'], how='left')
    df = df[(df['start_y'] <= df['start_x']) & (df['finish_y'] > df['start_x'])]
    val = df.groupby('start_x')['val_y'].sum()
    return val

def npb(df):
    s1 = df['start'].values
    s2 = df['finish'].values
    return np.sum(((s1 <= s1[:, None]) & (s2 >= s2[:, None])) * df.val.values, 1)
```

Comment: I dont think the dataframe used for the timing would give proper output for Pir's method.

Comment: @Dark - exactly, problem is only 6 groups so `.sum(level)` what is hidden `groupby(level=0).sum()` is really fast.

Comment: I think best is create new more general sample data and then testing... But difference is huge, so possible `comprehension` should be faster, but not so radically

Answer (score 7):

#### `numba`

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def pir_numba(S, F, V):
  mn = S.min()
  mx = F.max()
  out = np.zeros(mx)
  for s, f, v in zip(S, F, V):
    out[s:f] += v
  return out[mn:]

pir_numba(*[df[c].values for c in ['start', 'finish', 'val']])
```

---

#### `np.bincount`

```
s, f, v = [df[col].values for col in ['start', 'finish', 'val']]
np.bincount([i - 1 for r in map(range, s, f) for i in r], v.repeat(f - s))

array([ 100.,  300.,  500.,  700., 1200.])
```

---

#### Comprehension

This depends on the `index` being unique

```
pd.Series({
    (k, i): v
    for i, s, f, v in df.itertuples()
    for k in range(s, f)
}).sum(level=0)

1     100
2     300
3     500
4     700
5    1200
dtype: int64
```

With no dependence on `index`

```
pd.Series({
    (k, i): v
    for i, (s, f, v) in enumerate(zip(*map(df.get, ['start', 'finish', 'val'])))
    for k in range(s, f)
}).sum(level=0)
```

Comment: Add the timing and getting shocked :-)

Comment: @piRSquared what if there is a repeation of the interval say `(1,3,200)` at the end of the table. The approaches will add that to the first row which wont be cumulative.

Comment: Can you add more general timings, maybe with graph?

Comment: @Dark that would be the behavior I want; all I mean by cumulative is that I compute a separate value for each row/'start' value.

Comment: Oh ohk, @rinspy please add the output for the case where there is a repeation of the interval. I dont think the intervals are all unique.

Comment: @piRSquared - the comprehension solution assumes that the start/finish intervals are integers and are all close together. If the intervals are sparse it gets very inefficient.

Comment: @rinspy if they aren't integers, what are they?

Comment: It is fine for them to be integers, but ideally this should work with any comparable. But even with integers, if we multiply start and finish values by some large constant we would get problems.

Comment: @rinspy I can see that happening.  I believe the Numpy `bincount` method should work better.