# Pandas elements per week between start date and end date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm starting from a dataframe that has a start date and an end date, for instance:

```
ID START       END         A
0  2014-04-09  2014-04-15  5
1  2018-06-05  2018-07-01  8 
2  2018-06-05  2018-07-01  7
```

And I'm trying to find, for each week, how many elements were started but not ended at that point.
For instance, in the DF above:

```
Week-Monday N
2014-04-07  1
2014-04-14  1
2014-04-21  0
...
2018-06-04  2
...
```

Something like the below doesn't quite work, since it only resamples on end date:

```
df = df.resample("W-Mon", on="END").sum()
```

I don't know how to integrate both conditions: that the occurrences be after the start date, yet before the end date.

Comment: Please can you better explain what you mean by "how many elements were started but not ended at that point"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265238/cumulative-apply-within-window-defined-by-other-columns/53265509#comment93415297_53265509

Comment: @AlexandreNixon comprised between the START date and the END date.
For each week, I'd like to count the rows where START <= week < END.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[0,1,2], 
                   'START':['2014-04-09', '2018-06-05', '2018-06-05'],
                   'END':['2014-04-15', '2018-07-01', '2018-07-01'],
                   'A':[5,8,7]})
```

1- Find week number for each `SRART` and each `END`, and find `Week-Monday`.

```
import datetime, time
from datetime import timedelta

df.loc[:,'startWeek'] = df.START.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d').isocalendar()[1])
df.loc[:,'endWeek'] = df.END.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d').isocalendar()[1])
df.loc[:, 'Week-Monday'] = df.START.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d')- timedelta(days=datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d').weekday()))
```

2- Check if they are the same, if yes, then ended during the same week.

```
def endedNotSameWeek(row):
    if row['startWeek']!=row['endWeek']:
        return 1
    return 0
df.loc[:,'NotSameWeek'] = df.apply(endedNotSameWeek, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ID       START         END  A  startWeek  endWeek Week-Monday  NotSameWeek
0   0  2014-04-09  2014-04-15  5         15       16  2014-04-07            1
1   1  2018-06-05  2018-07-01  8         23       26  2018-06-04            1
2   2  2018-06-05  2018-07-01  7         23       26  2018-06-04            1
```

3- `Groupby` each `Week-Monday` to get the number of cases did not end during the same week.

```
df.groupby('Week-Monday')['NotSameWeek'].agg({'N':'sum'}).reset_index()

  Week-Monday  N
0  2014-04-07  1
1  2018-06-04  2
```